# The position of the .Include() in a linq statement?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lazy-loading

Are there any differences between having the include before or after the where as in the queries below.
If they are the same is there a prefered one?

```
DBContext.Items.Where(i => i.ItemCategory == "A")
               .Include(c = c.ItemCategories)
               .Include(g = g.ItemGroups).ToList();
```

vs

```
DBContext.Items.Include(c = c.ItemCategories)
               .Include(g = g.ItemGroups)
               .Where(i => i.ItemCategory == "A")
               .ToList();
```

Comment: both are same. its better to use "join" instead of "include".

Comment: how is the join better?

Comment: Please follow these link :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977392/entityframework-include-vs-join-performance  https://msmvps.com/blogs/matthieu/archive/2010/07/09/entity-framework-be-vigilant-with-include-method.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference.

The reason is that you are creating an *expression* which is executed when the expression is *enumerated*.

In your case it gets enumerated when `ToList` is called.

The underlying provider, in this case the Entity Framework LINQ provider, will take the expression and figure out what SQL it needs to come up with. And since the LINQ provider is in control of its execution, it can use the expression and look at it in any order it needs in order to correctly execute the query against the underlying SQL data store.